# When I click the change button inside the GroupBox the Name is changed in both the datagrid and the database, but the person's Sex is not changed

Tags: c#, sql-server

I apologize for my bad English, since I am Brazilian and I do not speak fluently. I was creating a test program for my studies.
When I change the data in the TextBox inside the GroupBox and click on "Update" the value updates in the DataGrid and in the Database, but if I alternate between the radiobuttons, the value does not change, does anyone know the problem ??
OBS: All the controls below are in a group box

Button Update code

```
private void AlterarButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (AlterarTextBoxNome.Text != "" || MasculinoRadioButtonAlterar.Checked == true  || FemininoRadioButtonAlterar.Checked == true)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("update Pacientes set Nome=@Nome, Sexo = @Sexo where ID=@id", conn);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", IdLabel.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", AlterarTextBoxNome.Text);
        if (MasculinoRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sexo", "Masculino");
            numPaciente += 1;
            IdLabel.Text = numPaciente.ToString();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sexo", "Feminino");
            numPaciente += 1;
            IdLabel.Text = numPaciente.ToString();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Dados Alterados com Sucesso");
        Load_Grid();
        Clear_All();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Erro");
    }
```

Comment: Not related to your problem but just wanted to give you a Heads Up. The `SqlConnection` class is optimised to be frequently created and disposed, you should make `conn` a local variable and declare it inside a `using(var conn = new SqlConnection(_myConnectionString))`

Comment: Adding to @ScottChamberlain https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/